# covariance of reciprocals of rvs

Tags: covariance, expected-value, moment-generating-function

Consider two strictly positive random variables $A$ and $Z$. Let $E[ ]$ denote expectations and $cov(,)$ denote covariance. Suppose $Z$ has unit expectation: $E[Z]=1$. Suppose the following equalities all hold.
$E[ A Z ] = E[ A ] + cov( A, Z ) = E[ ( 1/A ) ] + cov( 1/A, Z ) = E[ (1/A) Z ]$.
When can we conclude that $A$ is actually a constant and equal to one?
Obviously, if $A$ is identically equal to one, the covariances are zero and all the equalities hold. So there exists a trivial solution. Are there other solutions where $A$ is not a constant? I think it is possible for there to be other solutions but I wonder if they can be, in some sense, identified. What other restrictions might force $A$ to equal one in every state? Any help, please, I would be grateful. Tx. Obviously, Jensen's inequality forces 
$E[ A ] \geq 1/(E[ 1/A])$ but I am not sure that helps.

Comment: Suppose $Z$ is independent of $A$ and $E(A)=E(1/A)$ (which would happen when, for instance, $\log(A)$ is symmetric about zero). Then all your assumptions hold.  This gives a huge set of possibilities for $A$ which are non-constant.

Answer (score 1):

This holds, for instance, if $A$ and $A^{-1}$ obey the same distribution. A non-trivial example of such an RV, may be:
$$
A=
\begin{cases}
1/2 \;\;\text{w.p.}\;\; 1/2,\\
2, \;\;\text{w.p.}\;\; 1/2.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: Good answer. The one thing we know - in my application - is that A and 1/A, if not identically one, wouldn't have the same distribution. One application might be when $\log A$ is distributed as $N(\mu_A,\sigma_A^2)$ i.e. $\log A$ has a normal distribution with mean $\mu_A$ and variance $\sigma_A^2$. Further, $\log Z$ might also be normally distributed (with a non-zero correlation and, in general, different mean and variance but with $E[ Z ] = 1$). The case of $\log A$ and $\log Z$ being Gaussian (and correlated) might be a simple work-horse example. The next step would be to generalize.

Answer (score 1):

If $(\ln Z,\ln A)$ as you suggest is binormal, then
$$
E(ZA)=Ee^{\ln Z +\ln A}=M(1,1)
$$
and
$$
E(Z/A)=Ee^{\ln Z - \ln A}=M(1,-1)
$$
where
$$
M(s,t)=Ee^{s\ln Z + t\ln A}=e^{\mu_Z s +\mu_A t + \frac12\sigma_Z^2 s^2 +\frac12\sigma_A^2 t^2 +\rho\sigma_A\sigma_Z st}
$$
is the moment generating function of $(\ln Z,\ln A)$.  From this, the equality $E(ZA)=E(Z/A)$ implies that the parameters of the bi-lognormal distribution must satisfy the equality
$$
\mu_A = \rho\sigma_a\sigma_B.
$$